# make an ifnot statement and if statement in one line

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to make an if statement with 2 conditions.  One that checks if one variable is NOT present & does NOT matches the word "good2go" and the other that checks to make sure "body" variable is present.  I'm trying to trip the error message here.   Here is what I have and what I've tried, and none of it seems to work.

```
if (stripos($_POST['check'], 'good2go') == FALSE && $_POST['body']) {        
                $error = true; } 

if (!$_POST['check'] == 'good2go' && $_POST['body']) {  
                $error = true; }

if (!stripos($_POST['check'], 'good2go') && $_POST['body']) {   
                $error = true; }

if ((!stripos($_POST['check'], 'good2go')) && $_POST['body']) { 
                $error = true; }
```

How do I get this to work?

here's the entire code of contact_us.php  this has the validation code and the email code.

```
    $error = false;
  if (isset($_GET['action']) && ($_GET['action'] == 'send')) {

          // Winnie the pooh check
         //$t = tep_db_prepare_input($_POST['verify']);
         if (!isset($_POST['check']) && !$_POST['check']=='good2go' && isset($_POST['body'])) {
                $error = true;              
        } else  {  // Winnie the pooh Check

    $name = tep_db_prepare_input($_POST['name']);
    $email_address = tep_db_prepare_input($_POST['email']);


//IP recorder start
$ipaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$ip = "\n\nIP: " . $ipaddress;
$content = "\n\nName: ".$name."\n\nComments: ".$_POST['enquiry'];
$product = tep_db_prepare_input($_POST['product']);
    if ($product) { 
$product_text = "\n\nProduct Interest: ".$product; }
$content_ip = $content . $product_text. $ip;
$enquiry = tep_db_prepare_input($content_ip);
//IP recorder end


        }
 // BOF: Remove blank emails
// if (tep_validate_email($email_address)) {
// tep_mail(STORE_OWNER, STORE_OWNER_EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_SUBJECT, $enquiry, $name, $email_address);
// tep_redirect(tep_href_link(FILENAME_CONTACT_US, 'action=success'));
// } else {
// $error = true;
// $messageStack->add('contact', ENTRY_EMAIL_ADDRESS_CHECK_ERROR);
    if (! tep_validate_email($email_address)) {
        $error = true;
        $messageStack->add('contact', ENTRY_EMAIL_ADDRESS_CHECK_ERROR);
    }
    if ($enquiry == '') {
        $error = true;
        $messageStack->add('contact', ENTRY_EMAIL_CONTENT_CHECK_ERROR);
    }
    if ($error == false) {      
      tep_mail(STORE_OWNER, STORE_OWNER_EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_SUBJECT, $enquiry, $name, $email_address);

      tep_redirect(tep_href_link(FILENAME_CONTACT_US, 'action=success'));
// EOF: Remove blank emails
    }
  }
```

Comment: Use isset() to check if a variable exists.  Also, your if statements should work.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, i got the original comment mixed up, i meant the complete opposite. DOH!

Comment: !isset() will check if it doesn't exist, and !stripos like you have should work too

Comment: ok, i fixed original post now.  It should make sense.  i hope!

Comment: ok.  this doesn't work though:
if (!isset($_POST['check']) && $_POST['check']!=='good2go' && isset($_POST['body'])) {

Comment: You need another ) at the end of that, but it should work.  What do you mean when you say it doesn't work?

Comment: it lets the form go through.  i'm tyring to trip the error message so the form doesn't go trhough.  i'm checking now though.  It might work now

Comment: this still is not working for me.  It's letting the form still be submitted even when I have check empty or if it's set to seomthing other than good2go.     using this:
  if (!isset($_POST['check']) && !$_POST['check']=='good2go' && isset($_POST['body'])) { $error=true; }else{ run the script }

Comment: You'll have to submit more code, but this is all used after a form has already been submitted.

Comment: for the script to go through, any of these 3 things can't happen,  1. blank $_POST['check'] variable  2. a $_POST['check'] variable that is different than "good2go" 3. $_POST['body'] value is present.

Comment: These are all server-side POST-SUBMIT variables.  They will not prevent form submission.  For that you will need client-side operations (Javascript).

Comment: yes, after a form is all submitted.  i'm using honey pots with divs hiding the fields. so if bots enter $_POST['body'] value, it won't go through, if they don't enter a $_POST['check'] variable at all or it's different that "good2go" it won't go through either.

Comment: Please submit more code so that we can review the entire process.

Comment: there is the php code that checks the form.  If all goes well it lets the form go through.  I'm actually just enhancing this validation code so captcha is not needed.

Comment: ok, here's the portion of the form code   <div id="required2">
If you see this, leave this form field blank and invest in CSS support.
<input type="text" name="body" value="" /> <input type="text" name="check" value="" /> </div>

Comment: You'll need to post the entirety of the PHP validation

Comment: To test this I either put in a value for body or a different value for check or leave check blank.  If this php code would work it would pull up an error before submiting this form.

Comment: The PHP is not called until after the form has been submitted.  I have explained this several times.  Unless you're doing some other bizarre magic and can show that code, the issue is that you want the PHP to be used before it actually gets used.

Comment: i'm having a hard time posting a lot of code on here.

Comment: ok, check my original, it has all that code.

Comment: What is happening and what do you want to happen?

Comment: currently if check field is blank or equals something other than good2go, it still letting the email go through.   it's supposed to flag the error and stop the form from being submitted.  body is ok.

Comment: ahh, ok, that fixed most of it.  so now if check is blank and body has a value, it trips the error which is good.  But if i put in "wfadfj" for the check variable, it still lets the form through.  are we sure the exclamation point is correct?

Comment: isset($_POST['body']) should be !isset($_POST['body'])

Comment: ok, i used || on all and now it's working.

Comment: I posted an answer to this issue.  Please mark it as correct so that someone coming across this in the future will know how to fix the issue.  Thanks, and I'm happy you've got your validation working!

Comment: -1 for asking a question opposite to what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to your updated problem:

```
if (!isset($_POST['check']) || !$_POST['check']=='good2go' || !isset($_POST['body'])) {
                $error = true;              
}
```

The reason for the pipes vs ampersands is that you want to throw an error if ANY of the fields has issue.  Also, you want to check if body is NOT set vs IS set.  Glad this worked out for you!

Comment: This was my final code I used that works perfectly now:  if (($_POST['body'] || $_POST['check']!=='good2go')) {

Answer (score 1):

> and the other that checks to make sure "body" variable is not present.

```
if(stripos($_POST['check'], "good2go") !== false && !isset($_POST['body'])){
    //code here
}
```

Comment: i need $_POST['check'] to either be empty or not equal good2go and I need body to have a value so I can trip the error for testing. otherwise it lets the form go successfully through. Trying to build a honey pot for a form.

Answer (score 1):

According to PHP docs regarding the [stripos](http://us.php.net/stripos) function:

> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

So you need to change the first line to:

```
// Doing stripos checks you MUST use === (not ==)
if (stripos($_POST['check'], 'good2go') !== FALSE && $_POST['body']) {        
            $error = true; }
```

And to check if there is no `$_POST['body']` you can change the above to:

```
if (stripos($_POST['check'], 'good2go') !== FALSE && (!isset($_POST['body'])) {
```

-- Update --

According to your comment, you need `$_POST['check']` to equal 'good2go', then you shouldn't be using `stripos` as it will check for the existence of `good2go` regardless if it's exactly equal, or part of a string; 'wow this hamburger is good2go'.

So I would change the conditional to:

```
if (((isset($_POST['body'])) && (strlen($_POST['body']) > 0)) && ((!isset($_POST['check'])) || ($_POST['check'] !== 'good2go'))) {
    // Post body has a value and Post check DOES NOT equal good2go, someone is hax0rin!
}
```

You may want to read up on [Cross-site request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) as it seems right inline with what you are working on.

Comment: i need $_POST['check'] to equal good2go and I need body variable to have a value so I can trip the error.  That's my goal here is to try to trip the error b/c I'm trying to build a honeypot so when a bot fills in the body field on the form, it trips the error, but also the good2go needs to either not be present or not equal "good2go" because if someone or a bot is trying to use another form to run this script, these variables need to adhere for it to go through, and if they don't it trips the error.

Comment: sorry, i'm confusing myself.  i need $_POST['check'] to either be empty or not to equal good2go to trip the error.

Comment: Updated with code that will only trigger error if check !== good2go.

Answer (score 0):

No need for all those unneeded functions. What you are trying to achieve is:

```
if (isset($_POST['check']) && $_POST['check']=='good2go' && !isset($_POST['body']) {
   // your code 
}
```

---

However, ***As per the title of the question:*** Use a ternary statement. Syntax is as such

```
$var = <condition> ? <true> : <false>;
```

Comment: @dweiss. Ha ha, true. Now I fixed my answer. Please review your vote. Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't mean anything personally, just didn't really relate to the question at hand.

Answer (score 0):

> One that checks if one variable is present & matches the word "good2go"

```
isset($_POST['check']) AND $_POST['check'] == 'good2go'
```

> and the other that checks to make sure "body" variable is not present.

```
!isset($_POST['body'])
```

so, just put them together

```
if (isset($_POST['check']) AND $_POST['check'] == 'good2go' AND !isset($_POST['body'])) {        
  $error = true; 
}
```

Comment: i need $_POST['check'] to either be empty or not equal good2go and I need body to have a value so I can trip the error for testing.  otherwise it lets the form go through.  Trying to build a honey pot for a form.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['check']) && $_POST['check']=='good2go' && empty($_POST['body'])) { $error=true; }
```

Consider using `empty` instead of `isset` if your `$_POST['body']` can be present with an empty value.

Comment: i need $_POST['check'] to either be empty or not equal good2go and I need body to have a value so I can trip the error for testing. otherwise it lets the form go through successfully. Trying to build a honey pot for a form.